# Error using PutObject to write a file in an AWS S3 in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-s3

Edited to fix typo:
I use an AWS S3 bucket to store files in a Laravel project. It worked fine, and then I had to move the bucket to a new region. As far as I remember, it worked fine, but now it throws an error when I use PutObject(). I get errors, even after switching back to the previous region.

This is how I have configured the S3 driver in filesystems.php

```
    's3' => [
        'driver' => 's3',
        'key' => env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
        'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
        'region' => env('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION'),
        'bucket' => env('AWS_BUCKET'),
        'url' => env('AWS_URL'),
        'endpoint' => env('AWS_ENDPOINT'),
        'use_path_style_endpoint' => env('AWS_USE_PATH_STYLE_ENDPOINT', false),
        'throw' => true,
    ],
```

And this is my .env file for using S3

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=AKIA23ECJX*****
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=*******noVeTOWVgBPibqz0******

AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=ca-central-1
AWS_BUCKET=silkweb-canada
AWS_URL=https://silkweb-canada.s3.ca-central-1.amazonaws.com
AWS_ENDPOINT=https://silkweb-canada.s3.ca-central-1.amazonaws.com
AWS_USE_PATH_STYLE_ENDPOINT=false
AWS_S3_SILKWEB_URL="https://silkweb-canada.s3.ca-central-1.amazonaws.com/"
```

And when I use PutObject(), I get the following error:

Unable to write file at location: client/temp/99. Error executing "PutObject" on "https://silkweb-canada.silkweb-canada.s3.ca-central-1.amazonaws.com/client/temp/99"; AWS HTTP error: cURL error 60: SSL: no alternative certificate subject name matches target host name 'silkweb-canada.silkweb-canada.s3.ca-central-1.amazonaws.com' (see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html) for https://silkweb-canada.silkweb-canada.s3.ca-central-1.amazonaws.com/client/temp/99 {"userId":2,"exception":"[object] (League\Flysystem\UnableToWriteFile(code: 0): Unable to write file at location: client/temp/99. Error executing "PutObject" on "https://silkweb-canada.silkweb-canada.s3.ca-central-1.amazonaws.com/client/temp/99"; AWS HTTP error: cURL error 60: SSL: no alternative certificate subject name matches target host name 'silkweb-canada.silkweb-canada.s3.ca-central-1.amazonaws.com' (see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html) for https://silkweb-canada.silkweb-canada.s3.ca-central-1.amazonaws.com/client/temp/99 at /var/www/vhosts/app.silkweb.ca/vendor/league/flysystem/src/UnableToWriteFile.php:24)

What I find surprising is that is that my bucket name (silkweb-canada) is being prefixed in the host name:   AWS_URL=AWS_URL=https://silkweb-canada.s3.ca-central-1.amazonaws.com becomes https://**silkweb-canada.silkweb-canada**.s3.ca-central-1.amazonaws.com/client/temp/99

I am grateful for any suggestion to fix the issue.

Comment: 1. I don't think that `amazozaws.com` is the correct domain name. 2. Are you using a custom S3 endpoint? You would have to have a _very_ specific, top-of-mind reason for this and IIRC don't think that they use custom hostnames. You should likely remove this setting completely and let the library pick the correct value.

Comment: I believe that was a typo. I have edited my question to use a new region (ca-central-1) and updated the error message as per new .env settings.

Comment: Again, endpoint URLs are specific to the _service_ [eg: S3] and _not_ to your bucket or tenant. The only reason I can think of that you would ever use the non-default values are for purpose-specific segments of AWS like GovCloud or AWS clients in China. Looking over Karl's now-deleted answer I would tend to agree that the `url` value should also be left as default. In short: delete the lines setting `bucket` and `url`.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks @Sammitch for your comment. I posted the same question on laracasts.com  forum and got a reply that worked for me.

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/problem-storing-a-file-in-aws-s3

In brief, I removed the following from .env file to fix the issue.

```
AWS_URL=https://silkweb-canada.s3.ca-central-1.amazonaws.com
AWS_ENDPOINT=https://silkweb-canada.s3.ca-central-1.amazonaws.com
```